# Plotting data in Python with csv with timestamp in ISO 8601

Tags: python, csv, plot, iso8601

I am new to programming in python. I have a csv where the first column has the following format with ~thousand entries: '1.7314453125, 2022-09-15T18:17:55.444'

How can I plot the data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What libraries are you using to read the csv and load the data?